# Is the OR operator supported in ScyllaDB?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, scylla

How does OR condition works in WHERE clause for SELECT statements in scylladb.

I have created secondary index on email. Below query works fine and return result.

```
cqlsh> select * from test.d_emp where email='robs@ex.com';

 id  | dept | email       | first_name | last_name | salary
-----+------+-------------+------------+-----------+--------
  10 |   10 | robs@ex.com |        Rob |     Stark |   1000
   1 |   10 | robs@ex.com |        Rob |     Stark |   1000
 101 |   10 | robs@ex.com |        Rob |     Stark |   1000

(3 rows)
```

However if I use two conditions using OR operator it is giving syntax error. Even a simple 1=1 is also giving same error.

```
cqlsh> select * from test.d_emp where email='robs@ex.com' or email='robs@ex';
SyntaxException: line 1:51  : syntax error...

cqlsh>

cqlsh> select * from test.d_emp where email='robs@ex.com' or 1=1;
SyntaxException: line 1:51  : syntax error...

cqlsh>
```

Please help me to understand how to combine multiple conditions in where clause in Scylladb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CQL (the Cassandra Query Language, also implemented by ScyllaDB), does not have a general-purpose "OR" keyword (see issue [#12910](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/12910) - only "AND" is supported). The error message could have been, and should have been, friendlier (see issue [#1703](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/1703)), but ultimately tells you the right thing - that it's a syntax error - OR is not legal CQL syntax.

In your use case, `where email='robs@ex.com' or email='robs@ex'`, the solution is simple - just use the IN keyword: `where email IN ('robs@ex.com', 'robs@ex')`.

By the way, the `1=1` part also doesn't work, not even without OR, because currently CQL expressions are rather limited in their scope, in this case `column=value` is a valid expression, but `value=value` or other stuff, is not. Issue [#12906](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/12906) is one step towards improving that, but for your use case you don't really need it (you didn't *really* want to use `1=1` in your expression).

Comment: Nice answer!  I was going to say the same thing about the `IN` keyword.

Comment: but what if I want something like `first_name = ? OR last_name = ?`

Comment: @Shuumastsu - in this case, involving two different column names, one of them will not be the partition key so the query will be inefficient and require ALLOW FILTERING. Yes, I admit "OR" is useful for ALLOW FILTERING. It makes it unnecessary to send the two parts of the query as two separate queries which would halve the performance.