# How to use 'or' with 'where' clause for scylladb using phantom dsl?

Tags: scala, scylla, phantom-dsl

I'm using phantom dsl library to perform scylladb operations. Now I was trying to combine 'where' clause with 'or' clause but its not working.

```
db.object
.select
.where(_.businessEmail eqs "abc@gmail.com")
.or(_.homeEmail eqs "abc@gmail.com")
.or(_.additionalEmail eqs "abc@gmail.com")
.fetch()
```

**Error:**

```
value or is not a member of com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.SelectQuery[com.outworkers.phantom.builder.Unlimited,com.outworkers.phantom.builder.Unordered,com.outworkers.phantom.builder.Unspecified,com.outworkers.phantom.builder.Chainned,shapeless.HNil]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value or`?
      .or(_.homeEmail eqs "abc@gmail.com")
```

How can I use 'or' clause?

Answer (score 1):

The [where](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/v2.59.0/phantom-dsl/src/main/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/builder/query/SelectQuery.scala#L100) method from [SelectQuery](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/v2.59.0/phantom-dsl/src/main/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/builder/query/SelectQuery.scala#L36) returns again a `SelectQuery`, which allows you to invoke [and](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/v2.59.0/phantom-dsl/src/main/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/builder/query/SelectQuery.scala#L120) method that will be translated as an `AND` operator in the `WHERE` clause. If you look at the methods of `SelectQuery`, you will not find any of them that lets use the `OR` operator in the `WHERE` clause because [OR operator is supported in ScyllaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75863427/7214091).

In the [official docs of ScyllaDB](https://docs.scylladb.com/stable/), you will also see that a [select statement](https://docs.scylladb.com/stable/cql/dml.html#select-statement) doesn't have an `OR` operator and the same happens for a [select statement in CQL](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/dml.html).

There is an open issue in the [repo of ScyllaDB](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb) to [Add basic support for the logical OR operator in CQL](https://github.com/scylladb/scylladb/issues/12910). Not sure if that will be added to [phantom](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom) knowing that the last commit was [on Aug 16, 2021](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/commit/e35aeb956f0c77fff5411bd4f9104509545be958).